# Create Joomla Module > warning : JInstaller: :Install: Can't find Joomla XML setup file

Tags: module, joomla

I created Joomla Module by following [tutorial](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module) on joomla website, for the first part it works but after i added 2nd part of tutorial about [Creating a simple module/Using the Database](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Using_the_Database) it doesn't work.
i got warning

> JInstaller: :Install: Can't find Joomla XML setup file.

the 2nd part tutorial is based on 1st tutorial. maybe i've done something wrong in my XML file.
this is my XML file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="module" version="3.1.0" client="site" method="upgrade">
    <name>Hello, World 2</name>
    <author>Dhany</author>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <description>Belajar Module 2</description>
    <files>
        <folder>sql</folder>
        <filename>mod_helloworld2.xml</filename>
        <filename module="mod_helloworld">mod_helloworld2.php</filename>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
        <filename>helper.php</filename>
        <filename>tmpl/default.php</filename>
        <filename>tmpl/index.html</filename>
    </files>
    <config>
    </config>
</extension>

<install>
     <sql>
         <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/mysql/install.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
     </sql>
</install>

<uninstall>
     <sql>
         <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/mysql/uninstall.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
     </sql>
</uninstall>

<update> 
    <schemas>
        <schemapath type="mysql">sql/mysql/updates</schemapath> 
    </schemas> 
</update>
```

you can download my complete module [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-4VVCHQE4g4DR-7qqBDtQpW4hSgi3OB2/view?usp=sharing)

thanks for your help

Comment: If you are doing Joomla development then you owe it to yourself to register an account on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  Whenever you have a question that directly pertains to Joomla OR would benefit from the support of a community with intimate knowledge of the CMS and its extensions, then you should post your question on JSE instead of Stack Overflow.  After registering at JSE, you may wish to flag this question to be migrated by moderators from here to JSE.

Answer (score 0):

Remember `</extension>` should come at the end. Not in between. That should be the ending tag. Your code should looklike this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="module" version="3.1.0" client="site" method="upgrade">
    <name>Hello, World 2</name>
    <author>Dhany</author>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <description>Belajar Module 2</description>
    <files>
        <folder>sql</folder>
        <filename>mod_helloworld2.xml</filename>
        <filename module="mod_helloworld">mod_helloworld2.php</filename>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
        <filename>helper.php</filename>
        <filename>tmpl/default.php</filename>
        <filename>tmpl/index.html</filename>
    </files>
    <config>
    </config>


<install>
     <sql>
         <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/mysql/install.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
     </sql>
</install>

<uninstall>
     <sql>
         <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/mysql/uninstall.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
     </sql>
</uninstall>

<update> 
    <schemas>
        <schemapath type="mysql">sql/mysql/updates</schemapath> 
    </schemas> 
</update>
</extension>
```

Note: I also noted that your `updates` is a file instead of a folder. Remember **it should be a folder**.

Comment: Thanks, it works, i moved EXTENTION TAG to the END OF FILE. but about  "sql/mysql/updates" folder on SCHEMAPATH although it is successfully installed it gives me warning that says "JFolder: :files: Path is not a folder. Path: /mnt/data/vhosts/casite-1278786.cloudaccess.net/httpdocs/modules/mod_helloworld/sql/mysql/updates", i checked the folder in my Zip Module File there is no problem. the folder sql/mysql/updates does exist.

Comment: You first uninstalled the previous component or just upgraded it.

Comment: I did, uninstalled and install it again, it still gives same result,  it says `JFolder: :files: Path is not a folder. Path: D:\XamppInstalation\htdocs\joomla\modules\mod_helloworld2\sql\mysql\updates` 
  maybe you can help me check is there somethink wrong with my module ZIP here [mod_helloworld2.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zadX9ZteP2NoCHOfsxaf4cyi4JgcEER_/view?usp=sharing)